# Is the $\arg\min$ of a strictly convex function continuous?

Tags: optimization, continuity, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $Y\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ be compact and convex sets, and let $f:X\times Y\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Suppose that for each $y$, $f(x,y)$ is strictly convex.

Define the function $g : Y \to X$ as follows:

$$g(y) = \arg\min_x f(x,y)$$

Is $g$ continuous? If not, are there additional restrictions that we can impose on $f$ such that it is? Thanks for any help!

(Two similar questions have been asked but in "[Is the function argmin continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2823848/is-the-function-argmin-continuous)" there is no assumption of convexity and in the answer to "[the continuity of argmin on convex function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141823/the-continuity-of-argmin-on-convex-function)" it is assumed that $f$ is continuously differentiable.)

Comment: For each $y$, $f(x,y)$ is strictly convex so there should be a unique minimizer.

Comment: What if the minimum does not exist ($f(x,y) = e^x$)? Should you also assume $Y$ is convex (a discrete set is compact)?

Comment: Oops that's right. I added convexity as an assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ is strictly convex, there is a unique minimiser,
call it $g(y)$.

Suppose $y_k \to y^*$, and let $x_k = g(y_k)$ and $x^* = g(y^*)$.

Choose any subsequence $I \subset \mathbb{N}$, then $x_k$ has an accumulation point $x'$. Since $f(x_k,y_k) \le f(x,y_k)$ for all $x \in X$ and $k \in I$ we see that
$f(x',y^*) \le f(x,y^*)$
for all $x \in X$ and since the minimiser is unique, we have $x'=x^*$.

In particular, this shows that $x_k \to x^*$ and so $g$ is continuous.

The proof just relies on $X$ being compact and $x \to f(x,y)$ having a unique minimiser for each $y$.

Comment: Why does $x_k$ have an accumulation point?

Comment: Because $X$ is compact. Otherwise the minimisers could disappear off to infinity :-).

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question but how do we know that for any subsequence $x_k$ converges?

Comment: Any subsequence of a compact set has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: @copper.hat Small comment regarding your last point: $f$ also needs to be continuous right?

Comment: Yes that is one of the assumptions in the question.